# HTML Table top border on JTextpane

Tags: java, html, swing, html-table, jtextpane

I want to show only top borders of a html table in JTextPane. Below code works fine in Java 1.7 but in Java 1.6 border does not appear. Is there a way to do it in Java 1.6?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class textpanedemo{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String html = "<html><table><tr style=\"border-top:1px solid red\"><td>asd</td></tr></table></html>";

    JTextPane jPane = new JTextPane();
    jPane.setContentType("text/html");

    jPane.setText(html);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HtmlDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(jPane);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it "not working"? Is the border just not showing up at all? Or is it showing a border on all edges?

Comment: Borders doesn't appear. Edited.

Comment: Okay, I can replicate your issue and am working on a workaround. I will post an answer if I can get it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 1.6xxx only supports HTML 3.2 and lower, and therefore table borders do not work in Java 1.6xxx.

I have created a small workaround that I hope will work for you:

```
String html = "<html><table><tr style=\"background-color:red;\"><td style=\"background-color:white;margin-top:1px\">asd</td></tr></table></html>";
```

Basically, I set the background of `<tr>` to red, then set the background of `<td>` to white, and gave it a bit of a margin to show some of the redness from the `<tr>`. Unfortunately, the margin seems to show 1px of the red background on the bottom too, which I tried to fix but was unable to.

Here is the result running in Java 1.6:

[image]

I have also created a second workaround which is a bit more hacky than the last one, and shows only the top border:

```
String html = "<html><table style=\"background-color:red;padding-top:1px;\"><tr style=\"background-color:white;\"><td>asd</td></tr></table></html>";
```

The con of this workaround is that instead of creating new `<tr>` elements to create new rows, you need to create new `<table>` elements (with the same style) to create new rows. Here is an example of using two tables to create two rows, using this HTML:

```
String html = "<html><table style=\"background-color:red;padding-top:1px;\"><tr style=\"background-color:white;\"><td>asd</td></tr></table>"
            + "<table style=\"background-color:red;padding-top:1px;\"><tr style=\"background-color:white;\"><td>asd</td></tr></table></html>";
```

(Notice how there are two tables in that html, for two rows.)

[image]

Take your pick. They are both a bit hacky, but it's what you have to do to support old Java versions, I guess. :/

Comment: thanks for your efforts. I added "cellspacing=0" attribute for table in your last code snippet. Now it works fine for both Java 6 and 7.